# C - Why does my server socket stop receiving data delivered by send() after one request?

Tags: c, sockets, server, request, httpserver

I'm creating a program in c which listens to `GET` and `PUT` requests and routes them to an httpserver. The problem is that after about N requests (N = number of servers), the httpserver stops responding because it doesn't receive the data from the client after the first request.

I forward the data by accepting client connections using `accept()`, read from the client socket and put the data from the client in a buffer using `recv` until it returns 0. I send this buffer to the server using `send()`:

```
int connect(int from, int to) {
    char buf[BUFFSIZE];
    int n = recv(from, buf, BUFFSIZE-1, 0);
    if (n == 0) { 
       return 0;
    }
    buf[n] = '\0';
    n = send(to, buf, n, 0);
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return n;
}
```

```
int acceptfd = accept(listenfd,  &client_addr, &client_addrlen)
connect(acceptfd, serverfd)
```

I was wondering if I wasn't properly detecting the end of the client's input, but I print the output of `send()` returns exactly the number of bytes I expect, but server doesn't receive it.

The server works perfectly every time, when I make requests to it independently. The server receives connections similarly (I can't change the server), it accepts client connections using `accept()` and it reads from that socket using recv. To clarify, I do not have the server code, but I have my own that works similarly to the one that I am using for this project that I also tested with (the problem persists) :

```
char buff[BUFF_SIZE + 1];
int client_sockd = accept(server_sockd, &client_addr, &client_addrlen);
int bytes = recv(server_sockd, buff, BUFF_SIZE, 0);
```

Is there something I could be misunderstanding about `send()` or maybe buffers? I have tried using the O_NONBLOCK flag and I use `select()` to determine which socket to read from so I don't know if blocking is the issue.

Comment: The server doesn't receive it. What **does** the server do, instead of receiving it?

Comment: `int client_sockd = accept(server_sockd, &client_addr, &client_addrlen); int bytes = recv(server_sockd, buff, BUFF_SIZE, 0);` Is that the actual code? The `recv` socket should use `client_sockd` not `server_sockd`.

Comment: Do you mean your code is blocked in `recv`?

Comment: You can't just blindly read from the client until 0 bytes are read. That means the client disconnected, so you won't be able to send a reply back to it. And you can't read an entire HTTP request in a single `recv()` call. You need to call `recv()` in a loop and actually parse the client's request to know when it ends. See [RFC 2616 Section 4.4 Message Length](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4.4). Your code as shown is not a valid HTTP receiver, let alone will not work for HTTP 1.1 clients that use keep-alives to leave a connection open between multiple requests to the same server

Comment: @kaylum, no actually that is not the code. I don't have access to the server code, only my intermediary code, but I do know that that is similar to how it is implemented